# Why are too many column families in HBase a bad idea?

Tags: hbase

Most documentation and articles on HBase suggest that a schema in HBase should have not more than 2 or 3 column families. How does the number of column families impact HBase performance? Why are too many column families a bad schema design?

When does it make sense to create multiple tables as opposed to multiple column families to store data?

I have read the explanation [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#number.of.cfs), but don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the question is : why would you need multiple column families? Column families are not designed to organize data based on some business considerations, but rather on some technical constraints.
For instance, you may have one column family to store all fields-values, and one column family to store binary objects (PDF, images) which are accessed occasionally.
One or several HBase tables depend upon your use cases, but if the rowkeys are the same a single table should be sufficient

Comment: Are row keys normally put in a column family by themselves? I'm trying to understand how the number of column families impacts HBase performance.

Comment: My understanding is that you have one StoreFile per column family and per region. So the more families you have, the more files HBase will have to handle. Compactions shall also process all files even the ones which were not impacted. The rowkey is obsioulsy stored in each file with the cells

Comment: You have one **HStore** per column family and per region, each Store has multiple `HFiles`. This makes things worse, in this context :)